# Hide Show options value less values in Select box based on selection in another Selectbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was struggling to hide some values from Select Box less than values selected in another Select Box. Like; There are two Select Box for Age range selection Min and Max. I was looking to hide values from Max which are less than Min age selected. Finally, found the solution. Please check answer.

Comment: Hi Rory, Posted the solution. I hope, this will help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#agefrom").change(function (e) {        
        var selected_index = $("#agefrom option:selected").index()   
        var length = $('#agefrom > option').length;    
        for (let count = 0; count <= length; count++) {
            $("#ageuntil option:lt("+ count +")").show();
        } 
        $("#ageuntil").val($("#ageuntil option:first").val());     
              
        for (let count = 0; count <= selected_index+1; count++){
            $("#ageuntil option:lt("+ count +")").hide();
        }           
    });
});
```